# Angular tooltip. How to disable default browser's tooltip?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using "720kb.tooltips" in angular to show tooltip.

I have this snippet in HTML.

```
<img src="icon_info.png" width="20px" tooltips 
title="tooltip" tooltip-side="bottom"/>
```

This shows black background tooltip on hover however after a 1 sec, gray background tooltip appears (default browser tooltip?)

Is it possible to disable this gray background tooltip ?

I saw this gray tooltip in Chrome and Safari.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your HTML to followings

```
<img src="icon_info.png" width="20px" tooltips 
tooltip-title="tooltip" tooltip-side="bottom"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `title="tooltip"`, then the browser will definitely generate default tooltip. **Remove it**.